# Why making/building C apps takes very long time?

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake

Why does making a C/C++ app take very long compared to other apps (Java for example).

I am trying to build Ubuntu Unity, and it takes about 4 minutes on my local machine.

I think the process of Generating object files is the one that take most time.

Any advice?

Comment: Don't conflate C and C++. C generally compiles very quickly, while C++ is responsible for jokes like [these](http://xkcd.com/303/). Also, Unity is likely just bigger than any Java app you've compiled before.

Comment: Agree in first point, disagree in the second, I've worked on `spark` http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/spark/trunk and the compilation was very faster..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to speed up code generation you can use [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/). Also you can take a look at gcc version as older versions are known to lag behind. [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org) also supersede them a lot.

I'm not touching compilation speed bacause this is a **HUGE** topic. Starting from that C/C++ is a fully compilable languages, while in Java you never compile to the machine codes, you just generate a bytecode leaving everything else to the VM.

Comment: So, Java compilation is faster than C/C++?